# How to use phpThumb in zf2

Tags: zend-framework2, phpthumb

I have used phpthumb in zf1 but not sure how to use in zf2, looks like whole process is different, can anyone pls help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing ZF2 by using composer you can just require the phpthumb package:

```
https://packagist.org/packages/dannytrue/phpthumb

"require": {
    "dannytrue/phpthumb": "dev-master"
}
```

This should take care of installing it for you, and using it is going to be pretty much the same.

Comment: I installed skeleton application using git, i don't know at what point i should use composer

Comment: You can just modify your composer.json file to include the new dependency then run php composer.phar install